# OpenSSL DES read file

Tags: c

I'm using OpenSSL to encrypt and decrypt txt file with DES.
But the results keeps changing and the last part of descryped text keep missing or break....

[enter image description here][1]
this is first compile
[enter image description here][2]
and this is second...

You can see the differences btw two capture up there.

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
```

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/des.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

#define BUFSIZE 64

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char in[BUFSIZE], out[BUFSIZE], back[BUFSIZE], buffer[BUFSIZE] = {0,};
    unsigned char* e = out;
    int len;

    FILE* plaintext = fopen("test.txt", "r"); 
    FILE* cypertext = fopen("cyper.bin", "a+"); 

    DES_cblock key;
    DES_cblock seed = { 0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10 };
    DES_cblock ivsetup = { 0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xA8 };
    DES_key_schedule keysched;
    DES_cblock ivec;

    memset(in, 0, sizeof(in));
    memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));
    memset(back, 0, sizeof(back));

    RAND_seed(seed, sizeof(DES_cblock));

    DES_random_key(&key);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    if (DES_set_key_checked((DES_cblock*)key, &keysched))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set key schedule\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Plaintext: \n");

    int cnt =0;

    while (feof(plaintext) == 0) 
    {
        len = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), 56, plaintext);
        printf("%s", buffer);
        memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
        DES_ncbc_encrypt(buffer, out, len, &keysched, &ivec, DES_ENCRYPT);

        fwrite(out, sizeof(char),len, cypertext);
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
        cnt++;
    }

    printf("cnt + : %d \n", cnt);

    fclose(plaintext);
    fclose(cypertext);
    printf("\n ==========================================================================\n");
    cnt = 0;
    printf("Decrypted Text:\n");
    FILE* cyper = fopen("cyper.bin", "r");
    while (feof(cyper) == 0) 
    {
        len = fread(buffer, sizeof(char),56, cyper);
        memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
        DES_ncbc_encrypt(buffer, back, len, &keysched, &ivec, DES_DECRYPT);
        memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
        printf("%s /", back);
        cnt++;
    }
    printf("cnt + : %d \n", cnt);
    printf("endoffile");
    fclose(cyper);
    

    fclose(cyper);
    exit(0);
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0fwn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdG5C.png
```

Comment: If on Windows, binary files must be opened in binary mode.

Comment: Nope ignore last comment your comment solved all problems.. Thank you so much